# Sample size for paired Wilcoxon test

Tags: sample-size, paired-data, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I would like to perform a statistical test in order to compare the results of a new machine B vs the results of the current machine A. The data are in form of count values, that's why I am thinking a bout a paired Wilcoxon test. Here are the historical data that I have on machine A:

```
12 
3
2000
5
22
446
10
11
99
11111
1533
222
33
22
227
96
```

As you can see, the data are widely spread. Based on this information, is it possible to calculate the sample size needed for my Wilcoxon test?

Answer (score 0):

Not from that data alone. You need to think about what is the null hypothesis and alternative hypothesis and what size of (type 1 and type 2) errors are acceptable.

If you are trying to show the new machine is different from the old machine, you would need to make an assumption about how they might differ. For example, the new machine gives counts that are 10% higher on average.

If you are trying to show the two machines give similar results, it is more complicated.

Comment: And knowing how to transform the data before doing the Wilcoxon signed rank test is quite tricky.  The test needs the distribution of differences to be symmetric.  Do you log?  square root?  use the original values?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Yes I am trying to show the two machines give similar results. I aim to a type 1 error equal to 5% and a power of 80%. If I consider that the diff between 2 machine should fall between -5% and 5% in order to validate the equivalence, are these information are enough to calculate the sample size?